# Protege Subclass A controls Subclass B and Subclass C

Tags: ontology, protege

EVChargerDeviceFunction (A) is subclass of Function.
CancelSetpointCommandand (B) and SetPowerSetpointCommand (C) are subclasses of Command.

hasCommand objectProperty domains Function and ranges Command.

How do I let Protege know that the function subclass (A) controls the other two command subclasses (B) and (C)?
Is it correct to say a new "hasCommand" is subclass of "hasCommand",it domains (A) and ranges (B) and (C)?

Comment: Assuming`A`, `B` and `C` are individuals, then for `A` you have to add 2 object property assertions:  `hasCommand B` and `hasCommand C`.